# Consultar elementos de un spinner android studio

Tags: java, android, spinner

tengo un problema con spinner el cual he llenado con valores de una api, el problema es que al seleccionarlo no me devuelve ningun valor, es como sino lo estuviera haciendo, o sea como si no seleccionara ningun valor.

Otra pregunta al margen, el spinner solo puede devolver el texto del mismo y la ubicacion  o hay alguna foma de implementar un value propio como en los combobox? ejemplo.

Desde ya agradezco la ayuda.

**Texto:** Argentina
**Valor :** ARS

Les comparto el codigo, gracias.

```
 private TextView UserIdJson;
private Spinner Combopaises;
String[] strPaises;
List<String> listaPaises;
ArrayAdapter<String> comboAdapter;
String nombrePais;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    UserIdJson =  findViewById(R.id.idUserJson);
    Combopaises =  findViewById(R.id.Cpais);

    llenarCombo();
   // consultaAPI();

}

public void llenarCombo() {
    //Implemento el setOnItemSelectedListener: para realizar acciones cuando se seleccionen los ítems
    Combopaises.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    //Convierto la variable List<> en un ArrayList<>()
    listaPaises = new ArrayList<>();

    Retrofit retrofitCombo = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://api.mmm.com")

            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    final JsonApi jsonApi = retrofitCombo.create(JsonApi.class);

    Call<List<Posts>> call = jsonApi.getPosts();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Posts>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Posts>> call, Response<List<Posts>> response) {
            List<Posts> Lista = response.body();
            for (Posts post: Lista){
             //                    String Contenido = "";
                //Arreglo con nombre de Paises
                strPaises = new String[] {post.getName()+"- 
               "+post.getName()};
                //ordeno la lista afabeticamente
                Collections.sort(listaPaises);
                //Agrego las frutas del arreglo `strPaises` a la listaPaises
                Collections.addAll(listaPaises,  strPaises);

            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Posts>> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
    comboAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, listaPaises);
    //Cargo el spinner con los datos11
    Combopaises.setAdapter(comboAdapter);

    Combopaises.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            switch (parent.getId()){
                case R.id.Cpais:
                    //Almaceno el nombre de la fruta seleccionada
                    nombrePais = strPaises[position];
                    Log.e ("Pais", "Pais :"+nombrePais);
                    //   Toast.makeText(this, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, "Nombre fruta: entra ").show();
                    break;
            }
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para asegurar que se llene tu `Spinner` es importante verificar la respuesta, puedes imprimir cuantos elementos se obtienen, de otra forma tienes que revisar la API ya que no estaría entregando paises.

```
@Override
    public void onResponse(Call<List<Posts>> call, Response<List<Posts>> response) {
        List<Posts> Lista = response.body();
        Log.i ("Pais", "Lista contiene : "+Lista.size() + " elementos".);
        ...
        ...
      }
```

Para obtener el valor seleccionado usa el método `getSelectedItem()`:

```
nombrePais  = Combopaises.getSelectedItem().toString();
```